# Marker wont show up

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, marker

i try to put marker at my google maps that synced with firebase, and i had no problem on it. the problem is my marker wont show up on mapFragment....i think there is an error here:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location)
                        .title(user.name).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

so here is my code

```
public class ChooseGoogleMaps extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private DatabaseReference mUsers;
Marker marker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_google_maps);
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to 
be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.otherMap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    mUsers= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    mUsers.push().setValue(marker);

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserInformation user = s.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                assert user != null;
                LatLng location=new LatLng(user.latitude,user.longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(location)
                        .title(user.name).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

            }
        }
```

xml code:(please dont judge my messy code, im new at this...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/indo_launcherr"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/indo_launcherr"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login.Login">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Genre">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".All_Area" />
    <activity android:name=".Choose_Area" />
    <activity android:name=".Near_Me" />
    <activity android:name=".Popular" />
    <activity android:name=".Bookmarked" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.PasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.RegistrationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.UpdatePassword" />
    <activity android:name=".Login.UpdateProfile" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".home" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseGoogleMaps"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_google_maps" />

</application>
```

and here is the log:

```
13:15   Emulator: 

13:15   Emulator: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it 
in an unusual way.

13:15   Emulator: Please contact the application's support team for more 
information.

13:15   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 30s 304ms

13:16   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 255

13:16   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

13:16   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 16s 836ms

13:18   Emulator: ANGLE: egl::`anonymous- 
namespace'::CreateDisplayFromAttribs: make D3D display

13:18   Emulator: ANGLE: D3D11: rx::Renderer11::generateConfigs

13:18   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

13:21   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

13:22   Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1m 0s 160ms
```

Comment: t think marker was set to other place try to cross check lat long using Logcat or use CameraUpdate methos to focus on marker

Answer (score 0):

please check the following

1- you have internet access and internet permission in your manifest

2- that the data of the user is received correctly by adding "logs" inside on data change to specify the error

3- if there is anything printed in your log please show it to us also preview your XML code just in case

Note: this code will keep adding markers not updating